# Keyframing some object properties doesn't work

Tags: keyframes

I made a smoke simulation, and wanted to deactivate the "Use Flow" property of the flow object during the animation to stop smoke generation.

So I select frame 90, add a keyframe by clicking on the dot on the right of the "Use Flow" property while it is checked. Then I go to frame 91, uncheck "Use Flow" and add a new keyframe the same way. That way, it generates smoke and at frame 91, it stops.

Problem is, it doesn't. Actually if I click on any other frame, "Use Flow" is checked, even when I select frame 91 again.

I did the same thing in another file and it works perfectly. I don't get it, is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

In Scene > Time remapping I left Old on 100 and New on 300, so I put New on 100 and problem solved